# How to associate an iPhone with an Apple ID/account via iTunes?

Tags: itunes, apple-id, iphone

I'm trying to associate my iPhone 7+ with my Apple ID so that when I [log in to my Apple ID account](https://appleid.apple.com/#!&page=signin) I see my device associated with that account:

[image]

I have my iPhone connected to my Mac laptop and I have iTunes launched. Is there any way to perform this association through iTunes? If not, what's the easiest way to make this association between my device (ipHone 7+) and my Apple ID/account? Thanks in advance!

---

#### Update

I was able to follow @Monomeeth's steps up to step 3. Here is what I see on my phone screen:

[image]

Note I circled my desired device (my iPhone 7+) in red, so **yes**, I do see it there on that screen inside the **Settings** app.

So @Monomeeth's next step (Step 4) states:

> "*Ensure that you're logged into your Apple ID for iTunes etc*"

My question is: **How do I do this, so I can go on to Step 5?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something from your question, but...

1. Launch the Settings app on your iPhone 7 Plus.
2. At the very top you'll see your photo or an icon pertaining to your name. Tap on this.
3. On this screen you *should* see a whole range of settings, including for iCloud, iTunes & App Store, etc. You should also see your devices listed.
4. Ensure that you're logged into your Apple ID for iTunes etc
5. Assuming you see your iPhone 7 Plus in the list of devices, tap on that as well to verify the device.
6. If prompted to sign in to iCloud etc, then enter your password and tap OK.
7. If prompted to answer security questions, etc, then do so.

After going through the above process, do you find your iPhone 7 Plus is associated with your account? If not, then try downloading a song or app you've previously purchased with your Apple ID and check again.

Comment: Thanks @Monomeeth (+1) - I'll give your suggestion a try in a little bit! A few quick clarifications about Steps 3 and 4 above: **(1)** In Step 3, you say "*On this screen you should see a whole range of settings, including for iCloud, iTunes & App Store, etc. **You should also see your devices listed**.*". Are you saying that -- from inside the Settings app on my iPhone, I should be seeing a list of devices associated with my iCloud & iTunes accounts?! And **(2)** In Step 4, should I be logged into my Apple ID on my phone or via browser on my Mac laptop? Thanks again for all the help so far!

Comment: Re Step 3, yes, you should also see your devices listed, although you may need to swipe up as they're listed at the bottom of the screen. That said, this assumes your devices are (or have been) associated with the same Apple ID you've logged into via your iPhone. Re Step 4 I mean within that screen you're already on after Step 2. Also, if you happen to have separate Apple ID and iCloud accounts, make sure you've logged into both at Step 4.

Comment: Thanks again @Monomeeth (+1) - please see my update to the question (it includes a screenshot), any ideas how I proceed forward to Step 5 of your list? Thanks again!

Comment: Looking at your part screenshot, above where your iPhone is listed you'll see options for iCloud and for iTunes & App Store. You tap on each of these and sign in with your Apple ID.